# RavenDB - The media is write protected

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, ravendb

I'm getting an error when I try and run the RavenDB web managment console that "The media is write protected."

The site I'm working with is running on AWS with a VM with raven data on one SSD and raven indexes on another SSD for optimal performance. I spawned a compute instance with 8 Cores and 64GB of RAM to speed up the indexing as there are about 300k documents to be indexed in deep map reduces which takes two days to index when running on a 2core/8GB instance.

When I disconnected the mega-instance and reconnected the drives to a more modest VM and fired it up, I got the error. I figured with the above mentioned setup, where index, data and websites are all on separate disks, I could detach and reattach the drives from VMs at will.

Can someone please tell me there is a very simple fix to this?

Full stack trace:

```
    [IOException: The media is write protected.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +14381860
   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) +1578
   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost) +213
   Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexStorage..ctor(IndexDefinitionStorage indexDefinitionStorage, InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration, DocumentDatabase documentDatabase) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\Indexing\IndexStorage.cs:97
   Raven.Database.DocumentDatabase..ctor(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Database\DocumentDatabase.cs:231
   Raven.Web.ForwardToRavenRespondersFactory.Init() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Web\ForwardToRavenRespondersFactory.cs:120
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

Comment: I presume you are using EBS volumes? You can't attach and detach instance storage.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was a configuration problem.

Because I was attaching multiple disks, I needed to repoint the index location to a different drive letter as the order i attached them determined their lettering which didn't match Raven's web.config settings. The resulting mess ended up in me needing to reindex anyway. Rats.

I'd be interested to hear from anyone who uses this strategy to rapidly build indexes to see what process they use to make it all work smoothly.

Comment: As a further update to this question - The simplest way to do what I was trying to do is to just upgrade the instance type temporarily - I didn't realise you could do this.